# GlSurfaceView added to RelativeLayout

Tags: android, layout, view, opengl-es, setcontentview

i'm trying to follow a tutorial about opengl es 2.0 android on [this page](http://androidblog.reindustries.com/a-real-open-gl-es-2-0-2d-tutorial-part-1/).

what drives me nuts is the init of the view. See the code below:

```
// Our OpenGL Surfaceview
private GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Turn off the window's title bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // Super
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Fullscreen mode
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // We create our Surfaceview for our OpenGL here.
    glSurfaceView = new GLSurf(this);

    // Set our view.    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Retrieve our Relative layout from our main layout we just set to our view.
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.gamelayout);

    // Attach our surfaceview to our relative layout from our main layout.
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams glParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layout.addView(glSurfaceView, glParams);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    glSurfaceView.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    glSurfaceView.onResume();
}
```

i don't get the addview process here. Setting the content view to activity_main and then without any relation he adds the glSurfaceview to the relativeLayout.

Isn't that supposed to be somehow related?

Comment: Agreed that this looks somewhat odd. First of all, the `GLSurfaceView` could be made part of the original layout definition, so you wouldn't have to create it explicitly. Otherwise, I also think that the layout parameters would need additional attributes.

Comment: I just set the setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) to setContentView(glSurfaceView) so i can see my rendering. I wonder why i can't set my contentView to gamelayout and add my glSurfaceView ontop of that..